# duas listview na mesma tela mas so uma aparece apos a execusão, ajuda

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-adapter

Estou tentando fazer uma tela para um app, onde quero por um texto, uma `listview` e depois mais um texto e outro `listview`. Fiz os códigos, mas na hora de executar só aparecem apenas os dois textos e a primeira `listview`, a segunda não aparece mesmo. Alguém sabe me dizer porquê? Vou colocar aqui o código que usei.

```
package eeecw.cursoandroid.com.eeecw;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AvisosEventosActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_avisos_eventos);

        ListView listViewEventos = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewEventosId);
        ArrayAdapter adapterEventos = new EventosAdapter(this, adicionarEventos());
        listViewEventos.setAdapter(adapterEventos);

        ListView listViewAvisos = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewAvisosId);
        ArrayAdapter adapterAvisos = new AvisosAdapter(this, adicionarAvisos());
        listViewAvisos.setAdapter(adapterAvisos);
    }

    private ArrayList<Eventos> adicionarEventos(){
        ArrayList<Eventos> eventos = new ArrayList<Eventos>();
        Eventos e = new Eventos("Feira Cientifica E.E. ECW - 2017", "Venha participar com nossos alunos na feira de ciencia e cultural da nossa escola na terça feira dia 15/11/2017 das 13h30 às 16h. Contamos com a sua presença.", R.drawable.feiracientifica1);
        eventos.add(e);
        e = new Eventos("Feira Cientifica E.E. ECW - 2017", "Venha participar com nossos alunos na feira de ciencia e cultural da nossa escola na terça feira dia 15/11/2017 das 13h30 às 16h. Contamos com a sua presença.", R.drawable.feiracientifica1);
        eventos.add(e);
        e = new Eventos("Feira Cientifica E.E. ECW - 2017", "Venha participar com nossos alunos na feira de ciencia e cultural da nossa escola na terça feira dia 15/11/2017 das 13h30 às 16h. Contamos com a sua presença.", R.drawable.feiracientifica1);
        eventos.add(e);
        e = new Eventos("Feira Cientifica E.E. ECW - 2017", "Venha participar com nossos alunos na feira de ciencia e cultural da nossa escola na terça feira dia 15/11/2017 das 13h30 às 16h. Contamos com a sua presença.", R.drawable.feiracientifica1);
        eventos.add(e);


        return eventos;
    }

    private ArrayList<Avisos> adicionarAvisos(){
        ArrayList<Avisos> avisos = new ArrayList<Avisos>();
        Avisos e = new Avisos("Comemoração do Dia da Conciencia Negra", "No dia 20/112017 nossos alunos faram varias apresentações em comemoração ao dia da conciencia negra. as apresentações ocorrerá no periodo vespertino a partir das 13h.");
        avisos.add(e);
        e = new Avisos("Comemoração do Dia da Conciencia Negra", "No dia 20/112017 nossos alunos faram varias apresentações em comemoração ao dia da conciencia negra. as apresentações ocorrerá no periodo vespertino a partir das 13h.");
        avisos.add(e);
        e = new Avisos("Comemoração do Dia da Conciencia Negra", "No dia 20/112017 nossos alunos faram varias apresentações em comemoração ao dia da conciencia negra. as apresentações ocorrerá no periodo vespertino a partir das 13h.");
        avisos.add(e);
        e = new Avisos("Comemoração do Dia da Conciencia Negra", "No dia 20/112017 nossos alunos faram varias apresentações em comemoração ao dia da conciencia negra. as apresentações ocorrerá no periodo vespertino a partir das 13h.");
        avisos.add(e);
        e = new Avisos("Comemoração do Dia da Conciencia Negra", "No dia 20/112017 nossos alunos faram varias apresentações em comemoração ao dia da conciencia negra. as apresentações ocorrerá no periodo vespertino a partir das 13h.");
        avisos.add(e);


        return avisos;

    }
}
```

Comment: Adiciona à pergunta o xml da activity.

Comment: Posta o codigo do xml, fica dificil decifrar como vc esta tratando o layout das ListViews dentro da tela, ela pode estar configurada para ficar do tamanho do layout root, por isso deve apareces somente uma lista, mas ajudaria se vc postar o codigo do xml